# Autodeploy from Codeship to AWS(Amazon web services)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Does anyone know how to autodeploy java backend from codeship to AWS as a elastic beanstalk deployment?

I have tried to autodeploy my java backend from codeship. So in codeship I´ve created a project. This is connected to my github repository and I have  chosen elastic beanstalk deployment. After that the build success on codeship I can se that a zip file is loaded on my S3 bucket in AWS. But then when the zip file in turn updates on my elastic beanstalk environment, the health status turns from OK to degreaded. I´ve tried to upload the java jar file manually directly on AWS in my elastic beanstalk environment and that works fine... So my question is does anyone here have knowledges about why the zip file occurs something wierd on the health status on AWS elastic beanstalk

A commit to Github --> Automatically starts build on codeship --> Build success and zip file is sended to AWS s3 bucket --> From S3 bucket the zip file update the previous running version that is running on my elastic beanstalk environment --> And here it fails

Comment: what kind of  weird thing happened on the health status?

Comment: The health on elastic beanstalk turns from OK to Degraded when the running version uppdates and I think it is something that occurs on the way from codeship to Aws.